# How do I make a self start bike using a Hero Honda CD 100?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, electronics, custom, hero-honda

Very, very new to this community.

I want to customize my old bike with a self start along with user authentication via Bluetooth using a smart phone.  I can make the electronics part (Means Software and small work on hardware) only. I have no idea where to place the device on the motorcycle.

Any suggestions to help me solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site @mvaustin     What year is your CD100?

Comment: 2003~2005 model its not the old model(CD 100 ss)

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and put in some requirements.  Requirements make the world a happy place.  How much space to you need?   Is there a temp range for the service limits of what I assume will be a circuit board?  Do you have any specs on vibration?  Vibration is a real killer.  Think about your requirements for a moment and below your question, hit the edit button and bullet point them.  You will be helping someone be successful if you add in all the data you can.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!  +1 for your question, I really like it.

Comment: Thanks Ducatikiller,as you said there is temperature factor for the circuit board,there are lot of other parameter such size,power,sensor,...i will get back to this site after a small discuss with my team

Comment: Think of environmental specs (moisture, temp), vibration (engine and road) and space requirements.   Good luck!

Comment: you'd also need to consider the drain on the bikes battery, how long do you go between riding the bike? or do you deactivate the Bluetooth receiver when the bike is off?

Comment: Are you locking the front fork somehow? If not, I would think this would be a theft risk...  Or at least an announcement, here is my bike, it's unlocked and running and ready to go.  And if you do lock your fork, what are you accomplishing with a remote start capability?  (Never mind the hassle of managing a cell phone with gloves and helmet and zippered pockets and bright sunlight blocking the screen, etc...)

Comment: @zipzit the price of being cool.

Comment: @Moab  You are right.  I totally missed that.  Profuse apologies.   MV Austin, if you really wanna be IOT (Internet of Things) cool,  make a Is-my-garage-door-open mobile app detector, and sell a zillion of 'em to us old guys as "Early Alzheimer Garage Door Tool".  I hate to admit how many times I circled back home ... did I remember to close the garage door? (Gotta protect all the stuff, like [brake rotors,](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29611/can-i-stock-brake-rotors-or-brake-pads-for-more-than-a-year) that I've got stored in there.)

Comment: ZipZit:do you want the App or App+IOT (For Garage Door Opener) ..I can make that one..

Comment: Friends i am on huge confusion like what all thing should set for Prototype-1(Eg:Authentication from user via app,GPS positioning,etc) ...So i want All of you to list some of your basic Need while you take off your bike for a drive what parameter do you need the most(Like:theft control,GPS,Referring the road conditions like traffic,Deep hole on road,etc)...Just Full Fill your dreams of riding via posting this...

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with the bad news - if it's the CD100 model without electric start then it's a no-go unless you replace the engine (I'm inferring this from your statement "customize my old bike with a self start"). You won't be able to retro fit a starter to it as the cases and internals will not be configured for one. However, if the engine does have electric start, read on. :)

At it's simplest, your circuit should be made to activate a low current relay that can itself be tapped into the feed to the starter relay (in parallel with the starter button wiring) so it can energise it and turn the starter motor.

You then need to consider safety aspects - has the bike got any safety interlocks in the starter wiring? Look for clutch switches (clutch must be pulled in to start the bike) and side stand switches (side stand must be up to put it in gear). These are there to prevent starting the bike in dangerous circumstances (in gear or about to ride off with the side stand down). Don't try and work around these, work with them and fit them if they are not already on the bike. You don't want to try and impress your friends by remote starting the bike when it is accidentally in gear and it goes tumbling off the stand onto the floor!

Good luck with the project!